# What is the order sort for plot x axe alpabatical variable values and hwo to change it?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to show observations count per categorical variable in a plot x axe.

First i calculate observations count by alphabatical group:

```
`dataset.groupby(['COD_GRB']).size().values`
```

That give me this output order:
[image]

On a plot, for 'COD_GRB' variable in x axe, it's not an ascending sort from A to Z:
I have this output:

[image]

On the plot, i want to associate and show for each variable on x axe, the observations count.
So i have to get the same critere order for grouby and x axe plot. 
What is the order for categorical variabe in plot x axe by default and how to change it?

Thanks a lot. Theo

Comment: The order of the categoricals on the x axis is always the order you supply with your data (e.g. `plt.plot(["A", "Z", "B"], [1,2,3])` would come up exactly as A,Z,B on the axis).

Comment: Ok thanks but i don't supply directly value for x axe but df column. Here is my code:    ax = sns.violinplot(x='COD_GRB', y=xxxxx, hue=xxxxx,split=True,inner="quart",scale="count",cut=0,dodge=False,data=dataset). As you can see, i don't give an order .

Comment: But still, the order of categorical values will be the same as the order of appearance in the `COD_GRB` column. If you want alphabetical order you can sort the dataframe before plotting (`df = df.sort_values(by='COD_GRB')`)